# How to identify invalid parameter error in PDOStatement::execute()

Tags: php

I know that there are some general answers available at stack (I have read them) but I am failed to understand what I am doing wrong in below code snippet. I have logged all the variable values and they are correct but I am still getting error. I am watching this code from last couple of hours but failed. Code snippet is:

```
   global $connPDO;
    $userId = $_COOKIE["userID"];
    $currentDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sql  = "UPDATE project_progress SET
                      project_part_no             = :project_part_no           ,
                      progress_description        = :progress_description      ,
                      progress_update_datetime    = :progress_update_datetime  ,
                      cad                         = :cad                       ,
                      blds                        = :blds                      ,
                      p_floor                     = :p_floor                   ,
                      f_floor                     = :f_floor                   ,
                      bridges                     = :bridges                   ,
                      tracks                      = :tracks                    ,
                      p_veg                       = :p_veg                     ,
                      f_veg                       = :f_veg                     ,
                      obj_model                   = :obj_model                 ,
                      obj_place                   = :obj_place                 ,
                      spw                         = :spw                       ,
                      fence                       = :fence                     ,
                      ola                         = :ola                       ,
                      qa                          = :qa                        ,
                      progress_update_by_id       = :progress_update_by_id
            WHERE project_progress_id             = :project_progress_id        ";

    $queryInsert = $connPDO->prepare($sql);

    $binds = array(
        ':project_progress_id'                   =>      $_POST["recordId"],
        ':project_part_no'                       =>      $_POST["projectPartNo"],
        ':progress_description'                  =>      $_POST["progressDesc"],
        ':progress_update_datetime'              =>      $currentDateTime,
        ':cad'                                   =>      $_POST["cad"],
        ':blds'                                  =>      $_POST["blds"],
        ':p_floor'                               =>      $_POST["pFloor"],
        ':f_floor'                               =>      $_POST["fFloor"],
        ':bridges'                               =>      $_POST["bridges"],
        ':tracks'                                =>      $_POST["tracks"],
        ':p_veg'                                 =>      $_POST["pVeg"],
        ':f_veg'                                 =>      $_POST["fVeg"],
        ':obj_model'                             =>      $_POST["objModel"],
        ':obj_place'                             =>      $_POST["objPlace"],
        ':spw'                                   =>      $_POST["spw"],
        ':fence'                                 =>      $_POST["fence"],
        ':ola'                                   =>      $_POST["ola"],
        ':qa'                                    =>      $_POST["qa"],
        ':progress_update_by_id   '              =>      $userId
    );

    //echo $binds;
    $querySuccess = $queryInsert->execute($binds);

    echo $querySuccess;
```

And The error is:

```
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [&lt;a href='pdostatement.execute'&gt;pdostatement.execute&lt;/a&gt;]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in D:\wamp\www\Employee_Switch_Persons\Employee_Switch_Person.php on line <i>925</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0212</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2816136</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp\www\Employee_Switch_Persons\Employee_Switch_Person.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Employee_Switch_Person.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0248</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2836384</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>ProjectProgressAndCommentSave(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp\www\Employee_Switch_Persons\Employee_Switch_Person.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Employee_Switch_Person.php<b>:</b>39</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0249</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2843376</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PDOStatement->execute(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp\www\Employee_Switch_Persons\Employee_Switch_Person.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Employee_Switch_Person.php<b>:</b>925</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Comment: Set error handling to EXCEPTION and use try-catch. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php PS: there are a million SO answers about this, next time do better research.

Comment: Please add the error message _without_ the HTML. You got enough rep to know how to write a proper question.

Comment: Connection failed :SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of the last parameter in `$binds` ...

```
':progress_update_by_id   '
```

has some extra spaces at the end.  Remove these spaces ...

```
':progress_update_by_id'
```